# Javascript RegExp вставлять запятую каждые три цифры в числе до разделительной точки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Например у нас есть число 1000000.0000000 (миллион, округленный до 7 цифр после нуля). нужно написать регулярку, которая вставляет запятую каждые 3 цифры до разделительной точки, чтобы получилось следующим образом
1,000,000.0000000

Comment: Как вариант, без регулярки: `1000000.0000000.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits : 7})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000000.0000000"));
// => 1,000,000.0000000
```

См. [этот ответ на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/3832970) и [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ibPmfq/1).

**Объяснение шаблона**

- `\B` - позиция в строке, противоположная границе слова (т.е. между двух буквенно-цифровых или между двух небуквенно-цифровых символов, т.е. тут кокретно между двух цифр)
- `(?<!\.\d*)` - позиция в строке, сразу перед которой нет `.`, за которой следует ноль и более цифр
- `(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` - позиция в строке, сразу за которой следует одна и более последовательностей из трёх цифр, за которыми не следует ещё одна цифра.